# I want a delegate object to access a private field of the main object

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, delegates, structure, access-modifiers

I want to structure my code the best way that's possible and I am facing a problem.
I want to delegate the task of drawing it's data to another object. However, this other object needs to access a private field of the first object.

I have this piece of code:

```
class Grid {

    private val matrix = Array<Array<Int?>>(10) { Array(10) { null } }

    private val gridDraw = GridDraw(this)
    
    fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        gridDraw.draw(canvas)
    }
    ...
}
```

I want draw() method of GridDraw object to access matrix property. I can't do it if matrix is a private field and I don't want to make it public.

I don't like the idea of passing matrix inside draw method because in the future I would probably need to add more parameters to this method.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you want to make the matrix public? Is it actually possible to draw without the full context of the matrix?

The answer to that question will drive you to your implementation. At minimum, you will need to expose the necessary data from the matrix required to draw it (which is probably all of the matrix), or structure your `Grid` class such that it is able to draw itself.

Though if you are only worried about extending the `draw` method with more parameters in the future, that should be an easy fix. Create a `GridDrawContext` class that contains the matrix, and have your `GridDraw` class take that context object instead of the `Grid` itself.

Then you can just further extend your context class instead of changing your `draw` interface.

```
class Grid {

    private val matrix = Array<Array<Int?>>(10) { Array(10) { null } }

    // future field
    private val foo = "bar"

    private val gridDraw = GridDraw(GridDrawContext(matrix, foo))
    
    fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        gridDraw.draw(canvas)
    }
    ...
}

data class GridDrawContext(
    val matrix: Array<Array<Int?>>,
    val foo: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If GridDraw needs a matrix to be able to draw, make the matrix a second parameter of its draw() function and pass your matrix when calling it.

In GridDraw:

```
fun draw(canvas: Canvas, matrix: Array<Array<Int?>>) {
    // use the canvas and matrix to draw it
}
```

I don't know what all you have in GridDraw, but if it is just a utility function wrapper, you can probably remove its property reference to the Grid. It seems like your design has unnecessary inter-dependency since currently your Grid and your GridDraw classes have to reference each other bi-directionally.